# Generator interlock on subpanel

Tags: electrical, subpanel, generator

We have 400 amp service in our house. There are two 200 amp subpanels. The one is the primary subpanel for most of the house that would need a generator connected to it. The main box is outside and has the meter integrated, so I cannot access it without breaking the seal. Is it possible (code compliant) to use an interlock kit on the primary subpanel with a 50 amp breaker to the generator inlet? With the interlock kit making sure the main 200 amp breaker for that subpanel is turned off, would there be any possibility of a backfeed? Thanks

Comment: In most places a mechanical interlock is compliant.  But you need to check your local codes, which may vary a bit, before doing this.

Comment: Does your main box have a main breaker or breakers inside it?

Answer (score 2):

Your Interlock plan sounds fine.

You can only power one panel from the generator, but that's all you're trying to do.

The neutral-ground bond on the generator will need to be disconnected.  There can be only one system neutral-ground bond.